# Liver Server button is Not Visible in VS Code on MAC

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Liver Server button is Not Visible in VS Code on MAC.

I am using MAC OS Monterey 12.0.1

I am using VS Code for my practising along with live server environment. However, even after installing and enabling the extension "Live server", i am not seeing any button where it supposed to be.

I am a PRO windows user and started using MAC PRO recently (If this detail helps).

Below are my checks.

1. Installed the extension and reloaded the VS Code - Yes.

[image: Live Server Extension Installation]

2. Did i check the notification area (The Blue Bar at bottom) - Yes (screen clipping is attached)

[image: Live Server Button and Status bar]

3)Is the Default browser mentioned in settings - YES !! As per my windows experience, we no need to. However, i have mentioned chrome as my default browser (Screen shot attached).

[image: JSON Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I understood there is a fundamental difference here. In windows i can see that this option will work with any types of files even with a normal directory.

However, when it come to MAC i am getting this option only when i open a .JS file. Below is the scree shot.

My bad and feeling embraced, i don't know how did i miss this silly thing ??

[image: LiveServer Extension]